# How to match more than two samples?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, matching

I'd like to compare the average values of some variables between 3 different groups. I should control for some covariates between the members of these 3 groups. For that, I decided to use matching method. But how can I match between more than two samples? Should I match the first and second groups, then match the second and third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a matter up for debate. I would recommend you do not use matching. Instead, use weighting, or, if you don't have that many covariates or have a large sample, just use regression to control for the covariates.

If you choose to use weighting, I recommend the `WeightIt` package, which I have written for this purpose. For some reading on causal inference with more than two groups, see

Lopez, M. J., & Gutman, R. (2017). Estimation of causal effects with multiple treatments: a review and new ideas. ArXiv:1701.05132 [Stat]. Retrieved from http://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05132

McCaffrey, D. F., Griffin, B. A., Almirall, D., Slaughter, M. E., Ramchand, R., & Burgette, L. F. (2013). A Tutorial on Propensity Score Estimation for Multiple Treatments Using Generalized Boosted Models. Statistics in Medicine, 32(19), 3388–3414. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.5753